# Error No overload matches this call TS2769

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть интерфейс

```
export interface Product {
  type?: string
  id?: string
  title?: string
  date?: Date
}
```

В сервисе вызываем метод

```
  getById(id: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.fbDbUrl}/products/${id}.json`)
      .pipe( map ( (res: Product) => {
        return {
          ...res,
          id,
          date: new Date(res.date)
        }
      }))
  }
```

IDEA ругается на строку

```
date: new Date(res.date)
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(value: string | number | Date): Date', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(value: string | number): Date', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
```

Я так понимаю, что компилятор ругается, что res.date может быть не определен.
Но я не соображу как в этот стрим вставить проверку

```
if (res && res.date)
```

Comment: А почему просто не `date: res.date`?

Comment: Проект учебный, поэтому исхожу из того, что было в коде у ютубера, а я только изучаю Angular. Подозреваю, что возможно значение res.date может быть number

Comment: `res && res.date && new Date(res.date)`

Comment: можете в виде ответа оформить, а я закрою вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

конструктор [`new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) не может принимать `undefined`, однако `res.date` имеет тип `Date | undefined`, что не дает напрямую передать его в конструктор.

Для проверки перед присваиванием можно воспользоваться логическими операторами [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) либо [тернарным оператором](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Саму проверку можно вынести перед литералом объекта и использовать обычный [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else):

```
.pipe( map ( (res: Product) => {
    var date = undefined;
    if (res.date){
        date = new Date(res.date);
    }
    return {
```

либо напрямую в литерале объекта

```
date: res && res.date && new Date(res.date)
```